# SSIS ETL MySQL to SQLServer

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, odbc

How to extract multiple tables with data from MySQL to SQL in Single SSIS flow package?
I'm using ODBC connection  for MySQL.

Can it be parallel also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in SSIS preventing you from having multiple source/destination pairs in a single Data Flow task, or multiple Data Flows in your Control Flow.

If you add multiple source and destinations to a single Data Flow, they'll execute in parallel.

For multiple Data Flows to be parallel, just don't connect them with any precedence constraints. If you have some tasks that need to run before or after those Data Flows, you can place the Data Flows into a Sequence Container and then connect your other tasks before/after that container.

The MaximumConcurrentExecutables property (at the package level--from the Control Flow, go to View -> Properties Window) controls how many Data Flows can kick off at once.